# How to convert excelsheet to Hashmap in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Tried converting Excel sheet to Hash Map in Ruby by using Sheet2hash gem, but was getting error.

First i installed the sheet2hash gem then

```rb
require 'spreadsheet'
require 'sheet2hash'
puts Sheet2hash.class. 
wb = Sheet2hash.workbook.new '/Users/a.d/Desktop/AutomationTest/Automation/features/Parameters/transactions.xls'
```

And i am getting an error:

```
test.rb:5:in `<main>': undefined method `workbook' for Sheet2hash:Module (NoMethodError).
```

My motive : To make excel columns as keys and row will become values.

Comment: What is line 5 (the line in which the error happens) in your code? And you really have a `.` at the end of this line `puts Sheet2hash.class.`?

Answer (score 2):

Their gem works properly, but they have given the wrong code in their document. `Workbook` is a class within the module `Sheet2hash`, so you can't access that class with the `.` instead you have to use `::` and also, the class name they have created with the capital letter `W`. So write the following code, it's working fine.

```
require 'sheet2hash'
wb = Sheet2hash::Workbook.new '/Users/a.d/Desktop/AutomationTest/Automation/features/Parameters/transactions.xls'

p wb.to_a
```

Comment: Thanks its working now . How to get excel columns as keys and row as values?

Comment: @ArunaDang If you want to convert column as keys, then this gem doesn't support that. You probably have to use some other gems like `creek` just to read the Excel and then you can write your own program to convert the way you like.